# MVC trouble displaying model in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I have a very simple view

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCTryOut.Models.TeamResultsModel>
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}
<div id="grid">
    @grid.GetHtml()
</div>
```

I can put a break point here and see that there is data in the model and that the grid binds correctly (TotalRowCount is non zero) but the table it outputs is empty!

Any ideas why?

Answer (score -1):

Doh: my model object had objects in it not properties :(

```
class Model
{
   int Count;
}
```

doesn't work

```
class Model
{
    int Count {get; set; }
}
```

does

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.